# Code for python that im gonna use for a poker game but im getting two weird outputs

Tags: python, class

```
    from random import randint as rand
    from random import shuffle
    suits = ("Spades","Hearts","Clubs","Diamonds")
    class Card:
        def __init__(self, rank, suit):
            if rank not in range(1, 14):
                raise TypeError('Rank must be an integer between 1 and 13.')
            if suit not in suits:
                raise TypeError('Suit must be a string: "Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", or "Diamonds".')
            # The quick check above makes sure the card being made actually exists in a standard deck of 52.
            # If so, the card is created succesfully.
            self.rank = rank
            self.suit = suit
    def draw(): #Acts like drawing a card from a deck
        randCard = cardDeck.pop()
        return randCard
    shuffleDeck()
    def dealer():
        for i in range(1, 4):
           print(drawFaceUp())

    def player_hand():
        for i in range(1, 3):
            print(draw())


    dealer()
    player_hand()
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
output

10 of Hearts
None
3 of Hearts
None
Ace of Diamonds
None
<__main__.Card object at 0x015043D0>
<__main__.Card object at 0x015044F0>
```

I'm not sure why im getting those two bottom lines """<**main**.Card object at 0x015043D0>
<**main**.Card object at 0x015044F0>""" or why after say 3 of Hearts it proceeds to say None, I do have more code that I used but I'm fairly sure it's not necessary for my question, if you would like to see all of my code I will post it all.

Comment: Uhh what is `shuffleDeck`, `cardDeck` and what is `drawFaceUp`? Also, in Python it is conventional to use `snake_case` for non-class identifiers.

Comment: The rest of your code is necessary for a minimal working example.  We'll have a better chance of figuring out the problem if we have your working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing a Card instance, which currently has no defined way to represent itself as a string, so you got the default output. Add this to your Card class:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return f'{self.rank} of {self.suit}'
```